# Does Gears of War 3 allow local co-op + online co-op simultaneously?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

Does GoW3 allow local co-op and online co-op at the same time? I want to know if my friend and I can play on split screen from my house and join a couple of friends online. What kind of games are allowed this way (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/6862/gears-of-war-3-co-op-faq.html), yes, it is possible.

> **Does Gears support split screen play? How many players?**
>
> You can play 2 player split screen. The screen is split horizontally.
>
> **Is splitscreen with online play supported? (Combo Co-Op)**
>
> Yes, but both players must have Live Gold subscriptions.
>
> **Is LAN or System-Link play supported?**
>
> Yes, you can play any of the modes via LAN for the supported number of
>   players.
>
> **How many players are supported in co-op play?**
>
> You can play 4 players through the campaign in co-op.  You can play 5
>   players in Horde or Beast mode.

Comment: Did you mean to link a website in your answer? There's currently no link in the body of it, so I was wondering if you forgot?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Yeah, I forgot. I fixed it now though.